# Laravel relations pivot table name trouble

Tags: laravel

in my app I have 2 conversations types: normal private conversations between users and conversations for people which are interested of user product.

In my User model I declared relations like:

```
public function conversations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Conversation', 'conversation_user');
}

public function conversationsProduct()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\ConversationProduct', 'conversation_product_user', 'user_id', 'product_id');
}
```

Where 'conversation_user' and 'conversation_product_user' are pivot tables between 'users'-'conversations' and 'users'-'conversations_product' tables.

My conversation_user pivot table has conversation_id and user_id table properties, but conversation_product_user pivot table has additional property product_id.

In my Conversation Model I have:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}

public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Message');
}
```

In ConversationProduct Model I wrote:

```
protected $table = 'conversations_product';

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'conversation_product_user');
}

public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\MessageProduct');
}
```

In my ConversationProductController I have method to find user conversations:

```
public function showUserConversationsProduct(Request $request){
    $user_id = $request->user_id;

    //var_dump($user_id);

    $userData = User::where('id', $user_id)->with('conversationsProduct')->first();
```

}

**And there is my problem:** In controller ->with('conversationsProduct') don't take relation for conversation_product_user, but for conversation_user pivot table. I can't handle it why its happen if I add second parameter as 'conversation_product_user' in my relation:

```
public function conversationsProduct()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\ConversationProduct', 'conversation_product_user', 'user_id', 'product_id');
}
```

I need protected $table = 'conversations_product'; to point my ConversationsProductController@store where to save conversation, but I think that can be problem with recognise proper relation.

I really appreciate any help. I attach photo of my db relations.

[image: db relation]